# Line below the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {siunitx}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\sisetup       {output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,line join=round]
\def\yb{13}
\def\ac{42} % angle C
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\yb*tan(\ac)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{\yb/cos(\ac)} % hypothenuse
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}F$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$\textcolor{white}B$](B) at (0,\yb);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](C) at (-\yb,0);
\draw[thick] (A) -- node[right]        {\color{blue} $z$}
                          (B) -- node[sloped,above] {\color{white}hypotenuse = \num{\h}}
                          (C) -- node[sloped,below] {\color{white}\text{opposite} $= FG$} cycle;
                          \draw[thick] (B) -- node[sloped]        {\color{blue}$|$}
                          (C) -- cycle;
\def\yt{13}
\def\ac{42} % angle C
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\yb*tan(\ac)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{\yb/cos(\ac)} % hypothenuse
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}F$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$\textcolor{white}B$](D) at (0,\yt);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](E) at (\yt,0);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](m) at (\yt,-2cm);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](n) at (-\yt,-2cm);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{blue}{120}$](H) at (0,-2cm);
\draw[thick] (A) -- node[right]        {\color{blue} $z$}
                          (D) -- node[sloped,above] {\color{white}hypotenuse = \num{\h}}
                          (E) -- node[sloped,below] {\color{blue}$y$} cycle;
                          \draw[thick] (D) -- node[sloped]        {\color{blue}$|$}
                          (E) -- cycle;
\draw[thick](m)--(H)--(n)--cycle;
% angles, with angles library
\draw[thick] pic [draw] {angle=A--C--B} node [above,xshift=.8cm,yshift=0cm] at (C) {\ang{\ac}};
\draw[thick] pic [draw,angle radius=4mm] {right angle=B--A--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to put the line below the figure? Btw, don't mind the other code, I use it when it's needed.

Comment: Your code is MWE, but a bit messy! Please provide the context of the figure, such as the statement of the underlying mathematical problem. For the bottom line, you can use `\draw[|-|,cyan] ([yshift=-1cm]C)--([yshift=-1cm]E) node[midway,fill=white]{120};
`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fun, it is rather easy with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.25cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,2) \sansmath
\psset{PointSymbol=none, PointName=none, linejoin=1, linewidth=1pt, labelsep=2pt, MarkHashLength=3mm}
\pstTriangle(0,1.8){A}(-2,0){B}(2,0){C}
\pstGeonode(0,0){O}\pcline(A)(O) \naput{$\color{DeepSkyBlue3}z$}\uput[d](1,0){$\color{DeepSkyBlue3}y$}
{\psset{linecolor=Coral2, SegmentSymbol=MarkHash, MarkAngle=90}
\pstRightAngle{A}{O}{B} 
\pstMarkAngle[linestyle=none]{C}{B}{A}{$\color{DeepSkyBlue3}42^{\circ}$}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{B}\pstSegmentMark{A}{C}}
\pstTriangle(0,1.8){A}(-2,0){B}(2,0){O}
\pcline[offset=-15pt, linecolor=DeepSkyBlue3]{|-|}(B)(C)
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{$\color{DeepSkyBlue3}120$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just another very close way to approach this kind of drawing, in order to let you know how to do these measurement lines even when they're not horizontal (and without using any fancy library that would do it automatically):

[image: measure]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,quotes,angles}

\tikzset{
    measure/.style = {thin,
            {Bar[width=2.2mm]Latex[]}-%
            {Latex[]Bar[width=2.2mm]},
                }
    }
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily]
        \def\angleI{10} % tilt angle
        \def\angleB{42} % B angle
        \def\a{6}
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{0.5*\a/cos(\angleB)}
        \path   (0,0) coordinate (B) 
                (\angleI:\a) coordinate (C)
                ($(B)+(\angleI+\angleB:\b)$) coordinate (A)
                ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) coordinate (H);
        \draw   (A) node[above]{A} -- (B) node[midway,sloped,red]{\large $|$}  node[left]{B} -- (C) node[near end,above,cyan]{y} node[right]{C} -- (A) node[midway,sloped,red]{\large $|$} -- cycle
                (A) -- (H) node[midway,right,cyan]{z} ;
        \draw[red] pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {right angle=A--H--B};
        
        \draw[purple] pic [draw] {angle=C--B--A} node [xshift=8mm,yshift=4mm] at (B) {\angleB$^\circ$};
        
        \draw[measure,cyan]  ($(B)!5mm!-90:(C)$) -- ($(C)!5mm! 90:(B)$) node[midway,sloped,fill=white]{120};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understood the question correctly. But you want the black line below the figure? You could use for example `\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.6pt}}`

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{article}
\usepackage    {siunitx}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\sisetup       {output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.6pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,line join=round]
\def\yb{13}
\def\ac{42} % angle C
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\yb*tan(\ac)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{\yb/cos(\ac)} % hypothenuse
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}F$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$\textcolor{white}B$](B) at (0,\yb);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](C) at (-\yb,0);
\draw[thick] (A) -- node[right]        {\color{blue} $z$}
                          (B) -- node[sloped,above] {\color{white}hypotenuse = \num{\h}}
                          (C) -- node[sloped,below] {\color{white}\text{opposite} $= FG$} cycle;
                          \draw[thick] (B) -- node[sloped]        {\color{blue}$|$}
                          (C) -- cycle;
\def\yt{13}
\def\ac{42} % angle C
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\yb*tan(\ac)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{\yb/cos(\ac)} % hypothenuse
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}F$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$\textcolor{white}B$](D) at (0,\yt);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](E) at (\yt,0);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](m) at (\yt,-2cm);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{white}G$](n) at (-\yt,-2cm);
\coordinate [label=below:$\textcolor{blue}{120}$](H) at (0,-2cm);
\draw[thick] (A) -- node[right]        {\color{blue} $z$}
                          (D) -- node[sloped,above] {\color{white}hypotenuse = \num{\h}}
                          (E) -- node[sloped,below] {\color{blue}$y$} cycle;
                          \draw[thick] (D) -- node[sloped]        {\color{blue}$|$}
                          (E) -- cycle;
\draw[thick](m)--(H)--(n)--cycle;
% angles, with angles library
\draw[thick] pic [draw] {angle=A--C--B} node [above,xshift=.8cm,yshift=0cm] at (C) {\ang{\ac}};
\draw[thick] pic [draw,angle radius=4mm] {right angle=B--A--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\decoRule
\caption[a triangle]{A description comes here}\label{triangle}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, I would never have thought this was the actual question, but now, I think you're right! A,d we answered with some complex code for the measurement line!